# PHP Average of subkeys in an array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

```
Array (
  [JohnDoe] => Array (
  [id] => 23
  [name] => JohnDoe
  [logintimes] => 30
)
 [JaneDoe] => Array (
  [id] => 26
  [name] => JaneDoe
  [logintimes] => 9
)
 [Smith] => Array (
  [id] => 35
  [name] => Smith
  [logintimes] => 9
 )
)
```

How would I go by adding the logintimes to each other(, and then finding the average of them?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty simple to loop and get that

```
$counter = 0;
$total = 0;
foreach($array as $row) {
    $counter++;
    $total += $row['logintimes'];
}
echo $total / $counter;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using [`array_sum`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) and [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) too:

```
$sum = array_sum(array_map(function($item) { 
    return $item['logintimes']; 
}, $your_array));

echo $sum / count ($your_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, PHP >= 5.5.0:

```
$average = array_sum(array_column($array, 'logintimes')) / count($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to loop through the arrays, and use a sub-array reference to total up the `logintimes` values.  After you're done, you simply divide the total of `logintimes` by the count of array items.

**Example:**

```
<?php
$users = array(
    "JohnDoe" => array(
        "id" => 23,
        "name" => "JohnDoe",
        "logintimes" => 30
    ),
    "JaneDoe" => array(
        "id" => 23,
        "name" => "JaneDoe",
        "logintimes" => 9
    ),
    "Smith" => array(
        "id" => 35,
        "name" => "Smith",
        "logintimes" => 9
    )
);

$count = 0;
$total = 0;
foreach($users as $user => $values) {
    $count++;
    $total += $values['logintimes'];
}
$average = $total / $count;

echo $average;  //Output 16
```

Working example: http://codepad.org/uHpJnODv

Answer (score 0):

Think that this solution should be more efficient (PHP 5.5+):

```
 <?php
$users = array(
    "JohnDoe" => array(
        "id" => 23,
        "name" => "JohnDoe",
        "logintimes" => 30
    ),
    "JaneDoe" => array(
        "id" => 23,
        "name" => "JaneDoe",
        "logintimes" => 9
    ),
    "Smith" => array(
        "id" => 35,
        "name" => "Smith",
        "logintimes" => 9
    )
);

$count = count($users);
$average = array_column($users , 'logintimes') / $count;

echo $average;  //Output 16
```