# Working out averages using two dimensional arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am very new at coding in PHP and I am trying to find out the averages mark of my students so they can view it on an online form. How would I find the averages for the following using a two dimensional array in PHP?

```
             Maths English Science
Student 1     50     92      62
Student 2     84     71      76
Student 3     67     87      68
```

I would need the average for:

- average for student 1 across all subjects
- average for student 2 across all subjects
- average for student 3 across all subjects
- average for maths for all 3 students
- average for english for all three students
- average for science for all three students

This is what I have so far:

```
<?php
$classMarks = array
(
'student 1' => array(50,92,62),
'student 2' => array(84,71,76),
'student 3' => array(67,87,68),
'maths' => array(50,84,67),
'english' => array(92,71,87),
'science' => array(62,76,68),
);
```

Comment: Related: [Calculating the Average of Values in a nested array object (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48652356/2943403) and [PHP Average of subkeys in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25129786/2943403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to duplicate the data, you can just use:

```
$classMarks = array
(
'student 1' => array(50,92,62),
'student 2' => array(84,71,76),
'student 3' => array(67,87,68),
);
```

For the students, sum the particular student's scores, in this case `student 1` and divide by the count of scores:

```
$student1 = array_sum($classMarks['student 1']) / count($classMarks['student 1']);
```

For the subjects, since `maths` is in the fist position (offset 0) then extract all values in offset 0, `english` would be offset 1, etc and compute the average the same way:

```
$maths   = array_sum($subj = array_column($classMarks, 0)) / count($subj);
$english = array_sum($subj = array_column($classMarks, 1)) / count($subj);
```

---

But a more meaningful structure might be:

```
$classMarks = array
(
'student 1' => array('maths'=>50,'english'=>92,'science'=>62),
'student 2' => array('maths'=>84,'english'=>71,'science'=>76),
'student 3' => array('maths'=>67,'english'=>87,'science'=>68),
);
```

Then access the subjects by their key such as `maths`:

```
$maths = array_sum($subj = array_column($classMarks, 'maths')) / count($subj);
```

Comment: so for english it would be: $english = array_sum($d =array_column($classMarks, 'english')) / count ($d); ?

Comment: No, english would be offset `1` since it appears second in the array.  I have edited and I would use the second structure that I propose so you just use `english`.

Answer (score 0):

A foreach loop

Loop each element as a student key = > averages value
Then add them, position 0 1 and 2, then divide by 3 (3 scores). I broke it up so you can see the steps, but it can be done within 1 line.

Then create the new array holding the averages

```
foreach($classMarks as $student => $averages){

$averaged = $averages[0] + $averages[1] + $averages[3];
$averaged = $average / count($classMarks($student);
$newArray[] = [$student = > averaged];
}

print_r($newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get array with structure as in the question, you can calculate averages in such way

```
$avg = array();

foreach($classMarks as $k=>$v) {
  $avg[$k] = array_sum($classMarks[$k]) / count($classMarks[$k]);
}

print_r($avg);
```